# Derived equivalence of algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Given two finite dimensional algebra $A$ and $B$ with generator-cogenerators $M$ and $N$. Define two algebras $X:=End_A(M)$ and $Y:=End_B(N)$.
Assume X and Y are derived equivalent. Are A and B derived equivalent?

It is an open problem whether $A$ is selfinjective iff $B$ is selfinjective, see conjecutre 3 of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11856-016-1327-4.

A positive answers to my quesiton would prove this open problem to be true since derived equivalences preserve being selfinjective. (at least over an algebraically closed field)

edit: A generator is a module having every indecomposable projective module as a direct summand and dually a cogenerator is a module having any injective module as a direct summand. All modules are assumed to be finite dimensional.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the terminology, but does ordinary Morita equivalence imply derived equivalence? If so then $X$ is derived equivalent to $A$ and similarly for $Y$ and $B$ so... yes?

Comment: @DylanWilson I added the definitions of generator and cogenerator. Of course M will be no progenerator in general and thus A and X are not Morita equivalent.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: Why would they be derived equivalent? You have a certain tendency to ask questions in what looks like a fishing expedition...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Assume the thing I ask is true. Then also the open problem in the link is true since derived eqivalence preserves selfinjective algebras.

Comment: Yes, of course. That does not answer my question, though.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez those algebras (endomorphism rings of generator-cogenerators) are exactly the algebras of dominant dimension at least two. It is a very large class including for example Schur algebras $S(n,r)$ for $n \geq r$ or blocks of category $\mathcal{O}$ or higher Auslander algebras. There are many examples when such algebras are derived equivalent.

Comment: Yes. And why would they be derived equivalent in general? (My point, Mare, in case you are not picking it is that all this information belongs in the question. If you have reasons to expect an affirmative answer, or for want it to be true, or whatever, explain them in the question. You did not even spell out the fact that an affirmative answer to your question would answer the open problem (which clearly puts your question in the realm of open questions, which turn to be, quite often, very bad questions for MO))

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I ask the question because there could be an easy counterexample. If it is true, then of course it would be hard to prove since it answers the open problem.

Comment: If you know $X$ and $Y$ are derived equivalent, can you conclude that $A$ and $B$ have the same number of simples (up to iso.)? That's the first invariant I would look at here to test derived equivalence.